# Mejor Encoding para tildes y caracteres especiales con Java?

Tags: java, xml, byte

Estoy usando previamente la clase `javax.xml.bind.Marshaller`, junto con la propiedad `Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING` en UTF-8.

Ahora bien para la siguiente lógica:

```
byte[] bytes = out.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

String finalDocument = StringFormat.convertEncoding(out.toString(), "UTF-8", "windows-1252");

String compareDocument = new String(bytes);

if(compareDocument.equals(finalDocument))
System.out.println("Son iguales");
```

Hay dos puntos a tratar:

1. Para Windows funciona, pero para Linux no lo hace de manera correcta.
2. Existe algún encoding mejor para las tildes, acentos y caracteres especiales, independientemente del SO a usar?

Se agradece todo tipo de ayuda! :)

Referencia buscada: [Baeldung - Java Char Encoding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding)

Comment: No acabo de entender el escenario: Por un lado la variable `bytes` no la estás usando en la segunda sentencia. Por otro lado, ¿Qué quieres decir con que no funciona correctamente en Linux?

Comment: @PabloLozano, muy buenas tardes! Es similar a lo que comenta nicP., y lo estoy llevando a la práctica. Si ves otra manera, es aceptada también. Gracias y Muy Buenas Fiestas! :)

Answer (score 0):

Podes reemplazar el método `StringFormat.convertEncoding()` con una solución independiente de la plataforma, usando el constructor `String(bytes, charset)` o el método `String.getBytes(charset)` para realizar conversiones de codificación de caracteres.

Por ejemplo, podes convertir el `out.toString()` en una matriz `byte[]` con la codificación de caracteres ISO-8859-1 y luego volver a convertirlo en una cadena con la codificación de caracteres UTF-8:

```
byte[] bytes = out.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
String finalDocument = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Otra alternativa para hacer lo mismo seria:

```
String finalDocument = new String(out.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Hola, @nicP, saludos desde Galicia a la Campeona del Mundo! ;) Probaré con esta solución, seguro que tendrá muy buen aporte. Gracias! :)